# jboss-eap-7 - TCP messaging configuration

Tags: tcp, messaging, jboss-eap-7

I am working with "**jboss-eap-7.0.4.0**" I want to configure **TCP** connector to enable sending and receiving messages in Jboss queues, which some of them will be consumed by an inhosue middleware.
We have followed this congif steps given the jboss-reference

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/configuring_messaging/#jndi_entries_and_clients

I have defined this in our "**standalone.xml**" file

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
...
<!-- connector definition for TCP-->
<remote-connector name="legacy-remoting-connector" socket-binding="legacy-
remoting"/>
<!-- acceptor definition for TCP-->
<remote-acceptor name="legacy-messaging-acceptor" socket-binding="legacy-
messaging"/>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" 
port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
...
<socket-binding name="legacy-messaging" port="5445"/>
<socket-binding name="legacy-remoting" port="4447"/>
...
```

I have also configure a queue:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
...
<jms-queue name="SPID-Input" entries="queue/SPID-Input 
java:jboss/exported/queue/SPID-Input"/> 
...
```

but for the "RemoteConnectionFactory" i havent found the specification to enable remote-connector for TCP, the reference is useful just for http-connector (HTTP-protocol)

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
...
<connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" ****connectors="http-
connector"**** entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
```

"remote-connector"
"remote"
It doesn't work...

¿Any help/recommendations?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I guess my first question is...Why is the http-connector not suitable for your use-case?  The http-connector only uses HTTP for an initial hand-shake and then an HTTP-upgrade is performed and the connection becomes a normal ActiveMQ Artemis TCP connection.  This functionality was implemented so services with the application server can all "listen" on the same port which reduces configuration and administrative overhead (e.g. firewalls).

Comment: Justin thank you so much for your response, sorry because of my delay also...

Comment: http-connector is suitable for our case, because our app (one of the consumers of the queue - in java) can read and write from/to  queues, the problem is when another consumer (.net code) wants to do the same. NET Dev team argues that this is java syntax "**http-remoting**://host:61616" so we want to enable the communication over tcp.
For the **initial hand-shake** you commented we tried to make two "calls" one with **http-remoting** and the other one with **tcp**://host:61616 the first one works and the second doesn't.

Comment: Are we doing something wrong? do you have an idea of which is the correct line from .NET code to write/read from the queues defined over "http-connector"
Thank you...

Comment: There's nothing inherently Java-based about the syntax of that URL. It's just a URL. That said, I'm not aware of any .NET client implementations for JBoss EAP JNDI or the Artemis core protocol. What client library are you attempting to use to work with JBoss EAP?

Comment: In java we successfully tested with: **jboss-client.jar, javax.jms.jar** using **org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory** and the .NET client is using **Apache.NMS.1.7.1, Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.1.7.2** packages/libraries for the following code  **Dim factory As NMSConnectionFactory = New NMSConnectionFactory(tcp://host:61616)** this is over tcp because it doesn’t work with **http-remoting://host:61616**
Thank you so much

Comment: With your Java client you're using JNDI to look-up the JMS connection factory and then using the Artemis "core" protocol over a TCP connection. The .NET client has no notion of JNDI; it's just instantiating its connection factory. Also, it's using the ActiveMQ OpenWire protocol over a TCP connection. The ActiveMQ Artemis broker embedded in JBoss EAP supports OpenWire, but that isn't enabled by default. You'd need to enable that in order to support the .NET client (assuming that's possible). Aside from that you could use a standalone instance of Artemis (which supports OpenWire by default).

Comment: Thanks Justin you are totally right I ignored that JNDI works only for java clients I assume that "exported" in "RemoteConnectionFactory" and "queues" would work not depending on the language program just i have to worried about "connectors" and "acceptors" Do you have some reference about those alternatives you recommend for OpenWire? I am thinking about installing ActiveMQ [link] (http://activemq.apache.org/download.html) and configure apart from JBOSS...

Comment: I don't have a reference off hand for configuring OpenWire support in JBoss EAP. That's really a new question, and not something I would try to explain here. If you did want to install an ActiveMQ broker independently I would recommend [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/). It has OpenWire support and much better performance. It is planned to become ActiveMQ 6.x eventually.